# List all Font Awesome Icons in selectbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, font-awesome

I want to let the user select an Font Awesome icon when adding a link to my project. Is there a way to output an select box with all available Font Awesome Icons and there names?

I'm working with C#.NET, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the names from their SCSS file at https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss

Comment: How can I use the CSS "variables" in my project for building a select box? It isn't clear to me..

Comment: Just copy the variable names, and remove the prefix `$fa-var-`. `$fa-var-adjust` is just `adjust`.

Comment: I've figured it out but right now I have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31810285/3423987

Comment: You can now find that link at https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/web-fonts-with-css/scss/_variables.scss

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Compilation;
using System.Collections;

var dir = Directory.GetFiles(string.Format("{0}/The folder where the font-awesome file is in", HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath), "font-awesome.css", SearchOption.AllDirectories); var dir1 = dir.ToArray(); var tt = new List<string>();
foreach (var file in dir)
{
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line.Contains(":before"))
            {
                var index = line.IndexOf(":before"); var text = line.Substring(1, (index - 1)); tt.Add(text);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
ViewData["fontList"] = tt.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a git hub repo with a C# list of FontAwesome icons

Here you go

https://github.com/McHeff/FontAwesome_IconList/blob/main/MyFontAwesomeIconsList

[image]

As far as how you want to render this, that's up to you. You asked about using a selectbox, which I'm assuming is a dropdown list, I just worry about the performance as there are over 6000 icons in this list.